# NSURLConnection delegate method call only in viewDidLoad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I'm not seeing these two methods called when I start my `NSURLConnection`:

```m
-(BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace;
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
```

This worked when I created `NSURLConnection` in `viewDidLoad` but when I called this from another function, I'm not seeing `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` called. This is how I'm creating my `NSURLConnection`:

```m
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:video_link1]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Comment: yes you are right Rob

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, do not call `start` in conjunction with `initWithRequest:delegate:`. That starts the request already, so the manual call to `start` attempts to start it a second time, often with with counter-productive results.

You should only call `start` if you called `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` with `NO` for that third parameter.

Also, if this connection is called in a queue other than the main thread, you also may not see the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods get called. But, then again, you shouldn't update the UI in a background thread, either, so I assume you're not trying to do this in some background thread.

So, if doing this from a background thread, you might do:

```m
// dispatch this because UI updates always take place on the main queue

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
});

// now create and start the connection (making sure to start the connection on a queue with a run loop)

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:video_link1]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO]; 
[connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[connection start];
```

I'm using `[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]` above. Some implementations (like AFNetworking) with use another thread on which the app has explicitly started another run loop. The main point, though, is that you only use `start` in conjunction with `startImmediately:NO`, and you only use `startImmediately:NO` if doing it on something other than the current thread's run loop.

If doing this from the main queue already, it's just:

```m
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:video_link1]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; 
// [connection start]; // don't use this unless using startImmediately:NO for above line
```

Comment: now i declare NSURLConnection *connection to use globally and     connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; is in viewdidload and [connection start]; ready for connect button .Im doing right?

Comment: @ThananutK No. You probably should not use `start` unless you absolutely have to use the `startImmediately` rendition for some reason (e.g. you have to use the `scheduleInRunloop` method because you're doing it in a background queue). Otherwise, do `initWithRequest:delegate:` when you hit your button, but do not do `start` at all.

Comment: this is what i come up with --->connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];<--

Comment: @ThananutK Close, but don't try to do `scheduleInRunLoop` with `startImmediately:YES`. And why bother doing `scheduleInRunLoop` if you're just going to use the `currentRunLoop`? Anyway, I've updated my answer with two logical alternatives.